# How to properly align matrices with an overbrace?

Tags: matrices

I tried to solve this question by myself and now I'm looking for some help. How can I make the last two matrices parallel with the first matrix?

Here is my code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T2A,T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{titletoc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}           

$A = \begin{pmatrix}
2 & 0 & 0 & 0\\                         
0 & 1 & 3 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & -1\\
\end{pmatrix}$
=$\begin{matrix}  
\overbrace{
\begin{pmatrix}
2 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 3 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & -1\\
\end{pmatrix}}^{D:=}
\end{matrix}$
+$\begin{matrix}  
\overbrace{
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 3 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
\end{pmatrix}}^{N:=}
\end{matrix}$
\end{document}
```

[image: Image showing three matrices, one without an overbrace and two with. The matrices with overbraces are shown lower down than the other matrix]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Provide your preamble or full code with the question.

Comment: Why do you use 3 separate inline-math instances? Why do you encase 2 of the 3 `pmatrix` environments in `matrix` environments?

Comment: thanks for the answer, i just learned latex, so some parts are still a bit complicated for me, i watched some videos on youtube but i still cant solve the problem....

Answer (score 7):

[image]

Just use `pmatrix` alone.

```
\documentclass{amsart}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
A =
    \begin{pmatrix}
        2 & 0 & 0 & 0\\                         
        0 & 1 & 3 & 0\\
        0 & 0 & 1 & 0\\
        0 & 0 & 0 & -1\\
    \end{pmatrix}
=
\overbrace{
    \begin{pmatrix}
        2 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
        0 & 1 & 3 & 0\\
        0 & 0 & 1 & 0\\
        0 & 0 & 0 & -1\\
    \end{pmatrix}
}^{D:=}
+
\overbrace{
    \begin{pmatrix}
        0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
        0 & 0 & 3 & 0\\
        0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
        0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
    \end{pmatrix}
}^{N:=}
\end{equation*}
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: thank you very very much!

Answer (score 6):

There are two separate issues with your code; both are causing the misalignment.

- You use three three separate (inline) math instances instead of single math instance.
- You are inappropriately encasing the 2nd and 3rd `pmatrix` environments in `matrix` environments.

In addition to fixing these two issues, you should probably also be looking into using display math rather than inline math, in order to give the formula more visual prominence.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}      % for 'pmatrix' and 'matrix' environments
                          % and '\overbrace' macro
\usepackage{showframe}    % draw framelines around textblock
\setlength\parindent{0pt} % just for this example
\begin{document}
before:

$A = \begin{pmatrix}
2 & 0 & 0 & 0\\                         
0 & 1 & 3 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & -1\\
\end{pmatrix}$
= 
$\begin{matrix}
\overbrace{
\begin{pmatrix}
2 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 3 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & -1\\
\end{pmatrix}}^{D:=}
\end{matrix}$
+ 
$\begin{matrix}
\overbrace{
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 3 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
\end{pmatrix}}^{N:=}
\end{matrix}$


\bigskip
inline math mode:

$
A = \begin{pmatrix}
2 & 0 & 0 & 0\\                         
0 & 1 & 3 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & -1
\end{pmatrix}
=
\overbrace{
\begin{pmatrix}
2 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 3 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & -1
\end{pmatrix}}^{D:=}
+
\overbrace{
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 3 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}}^{N:=}
$


\bigskip\medskip
display math mode
\[
A = \begin{pmatrix}
2 & 0 & 0 & 0\\                         
0 & 1 & 3 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & -1
\end{pmatrix}
=
\overbrace{
\begin{pmatrix}
2 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 3 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & -1
\end{pmatrix}}^{D:=}
+
\overbrace{
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 3 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}}^{N:=}
\]

\end{document}
```

---

*Addendum*: If you want to reduce the width of the curly braces generated by the `\overbrace` instructions, you could do so along the lines of the following code. The matrix on the left is as in the code above; the one on the right (a) places the tall parentheses outside the scope of the `\overbrace` directive and (b) uses a `\smash` directive and a tall typographic strut to determine the height of the tall parentheses. (Hint: the tall parentheses must be tall enough to encase a four-row matrix, but no taller.)

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} 
%% Define a (typographic) strut that's as tall as a four-row matrix:
\newcommand\bigstrut{\vphantom{\begin{matrix} 0\\0\\0\\0 \end{matrix}}}
\usepackage{mleftright} % for '\mleft' and '\mright' macros

\begin{document}
\[
\overbrace{
  \begin{pmatrix}
  0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
  0 & 0 & 3 & 0\\
  0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
  0 & 0 & 0 & 0
  \end{pmatrix}}^{N:=}
\quad\text{vs.}\quad
\mleft(\, % tall opening parenthesis, followed by thinspace
\smash{\overbrace{
  \begin{matrix}
  0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
  0 & 0 & 3 & 0\\
  0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
  0 & 0 & 0 & 0
  \end{matrix}}^{N:=}}
\bigstrut  % insert a tall typographic strut
\,\mright) % thinspace, followed by tall closing parenthesis
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, I will continue to work hard on the road of learning latex

Comment: @nus - You're most welcome. Please also note the addendum to my initial answer, where I discuss how to reduce the widths of the curly braces created by the `\overbrace` directives.

Answer (score 2):

If you want a solution with a reduced width of the curly braces, as suggested by Mico in its answer, you can also try `nicematrix` (≥ 6.4 of 2021-11-23):

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
A =
    \begin{pmatrix}
        2 & 0 & 0 & 0\\                         
        0 & 1 & 3 & 0\\
        0 & 0 & 1 & 0\\
        0 & 0 & 0 & -1\\
    \end{pmatrix}
=
    \begin{pNiceMatrix}
        2 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
        0 & 1 & 3 & 0\\
        0 & 0 & 1 & 0\\
        0 & 0 & 0 & -1\\
    \CodeAfter
       \OverBrace[shorten,yshift=1mm]{1-1}{4-4}{\scriptstyle D:=}
    \end{pNiceMatrix}
+
    \begin{pNiceMatrix}
        0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
        0 & 0 & 3 & 0\\
        0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
        0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
    \CodeAfter
       \OverBrace[shorten,yshift=1mm]{1-1}{4-4}{\scriptstyle N:=}
    \end{pNiceMatrix}
\end{equation*}
    
\end{document}
```

You need several compilations (because `nicematrix` uses PGF/Tikz nodes under the hood).

[image: Output of the above code]

Be aware that the braces and their labels are in an overlapping position.